# Decrypt webpage cookies

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, cookies, encryption

I have a rails website, how do I write a program to decrypt a webpage's cookies in JAVA?

```
For example, I have the cookies from my rails webpage:
issp_session=BAh7CEkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRkkiJWVhODhhYmMyMjgwNDA2M2NkNjI2ZjE5MWM5ZjVkYzlkBjsAVEkiFmFjY291bnRfcmV0dXJuX3RvBjsARiIGL0kiEF9jc3JmX3Rva2VuBjsARkkiMTJpOUszQmFablpnSkJvYW5JaFk5dWdWWGFWV3M2K0dTNXVwcFhZbzkxWFU9BjsARg%3D%3D--7f3a5f578c9199ed11d44f0deb842dde9e267e8b
```

I know
`BAh7CEkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRkkiJWVhODhhYmMyMjgwNDA2M2NkNjI2ZjE5MWM5ZjVkYzlkBjsAVEkiFmFjY291bnRfcmV0dXJuX3RvBjsARiIGL0kiEF9jc3JmX3Rva2VuBjsARkkiMTJpOUszQmFablpnSkJvYW5JaFk5dWdWWGFWV3M2K0dTNXVwcFhZbzkxWFU9BjsARg%3D%3D--7f3a5f578c9199ed11d44f0deb842dde9e267e8b` is the cookies that has been encoded and `7f3a5f578c9199ed11d44f0deb842dde9e267e8b` is the key of this cookies.

So my question is how do I write a program to actually decrypt this cookies?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should look for libraries to decode `base64` encoding to get the binary data.

If your application is configured correctly, however, you shouldn't be able to deduce any meaningful data. The application uses XSRF cookies that are HMAC-signed and sometimes also encrypted.

Comment: What can I do after I get the binary data?

Comment: The binary data is not really useful as-is (because it's encrypted). What do you intend to do with it?

Comment: I want to decrypt the cookies so every time I get to this webpage then my application knows :"Oh, this is the webpage that I am looking for!" So then I could do something else.

Comment: Why don't you just add another cleartext cookie (e.g. with the application name)? To my knowledge what you intend to do isn't possible with session cookies, especially not if your application needs to be secure.

Answer (score 0):

You should find out the algorithm used to encrypt/decrypt the cookie that Rails uses and then translate that to Java.

A while back, I have provided the answer for [How to decrypt a Rails 5 session cookie manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42703115/1137142) and used my Ruby implementation to translate that to Lua ([my gist](https://gist.github.com/mbyczkowski/9b64652e3472ec8a463069db8b84ae7f)), so I could decrypt Rails session cookie in Nginx.