# Integration Test Session not loading Session Cookie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Rails version: 5.1.1, upgrading from 4.2.7

I have an integration test (inherting from ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest) which hits a URL. The controller at that URL puts some stuff into the session. The test then tries to assert that certain values are now present in the session.

My session_store.rb:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_companySite_session', expire_after: 1.year
```

What I'm finding is that the session variable, called from the integration test as 'session', is always an empty hash ({}).

If I look at request.host in the test, I see "www.example.com". If I look at response.cookies or cookies, I see:

```
#<Rack::Test::Cookie:0x00000006037108
@default_host="www.example.com",
@name="_companySite_session",
@name_value_raw=
 "_companySite_session=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%3D--f253c4e1678e53896a247b087e741cf006c5874f",
@options={"path"=>"/", "expires"=>"Fri, 08 Jun 2018 19:46:22 -0000", "HttpOnly"=>nil, "domain"=>"www.example.com"},
@value=
 "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--f253c4e1678e53896a247b087e741cf006c5874f">
```

In other words, the session cookie seems to be present, and its domain seems to match the request's host. I've also used the code from [How to decrypt a Rails 5 session cookie manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474176/how-to-decrypt-a-rails-5-session-cookie-manually) to print out the value of this cookie, and the value is correct.

My test environment's config specifies   config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false

At this point, I'm out of ideas. The cookie is there, it seems fine, its set to the domain of the request, its not expired, but session remains an empty hash. Is it not getting updated somehow? Is it trying to update but failing silently? I've run out of things to try.

This test works fine under Rails 4.2.7.

While I haven't dived into it as fully, I've also been finding that tests' flash variable always seems to be empty, too. Again, tests that worked fine in Rails 4 are breaking because the flash always seems to be empty. I assume the flash and the session are related, so maybe the same problem affects them both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that we had this setting in our test.rb environment file:

```
config.allow_concurrency = false
```

For some reason, after making a request in the test, this setting causes the session to be replaced with an empty hash. Rails' docs suggest that you not set this flag directly: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/configuring.html.

I think this is something we had set in Rails 2, then got carried into Rails 4 when we upgraded, and now breaks in Rails 5.

I've logged it as an issue in the Rails repo: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/29608